# Message Class of received email in outlook is IPM.NOTE

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

I have a VSTO outlook add-in which specifies that the message class of my outbound mail to be IPM.Note.Secure.

However , when the email reaches the inbox of the recipient , the message class changes to IPM.Note instead.

I have checked my sent items and the message is indeed sent with a message class of IPM.NOTE.Secure.

Please advice if there's any steps that i should take note of when changing the message class .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PR_MESSAGE_CLASS is a MAPI property, it will be lost when the message is converted to MIME when it is sent through an SMTP server.

You can force Outlook to send in the RTF format (the infamnous winmail.dat file) which will preserve all transmittable MAPI properties. Try to set the UseTnef (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B`) property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works fine now. 

The weird thing about this is that, the message class sets just fine in an exchange server (without the addition of your suggestion) but when I test the same add-in on my other machine which connects to microsoft outlook(SMTP(?)), I need to use your suggestion to get the messageclass of the email to be sent out correctly .

Comment: To put it shortly , is there any other way I can preserve the MAPI properties before I send out the email so that the messageclass will reflect correctly in the recipient's inbox (independent of the type of server used) ?

Comment: Exchange does not convert the message to MIME when sending between mailboxes, so no properties are lost. Sending in the TNEF format is the only way if you are using SMTP.

Comment: In that case,in your opinion,what could be the possible reasons for the messageclass not being set properly?Here's my problem so far,my add-in works fine with other users using the exchange server, i.e , the messageclass of the email gets sent and received correctly. However, there's only one user where his message got sent successfully, but the messageclass does not appear correctly in the recipient's inbox. He is in the exchange server as well. it seems like there's always a problem with his machine when it comes to setting/clearing MAPI properties. Does outlook need an additional setting ?